# I have a txt file of 100 items. Each line starts with ", (digit)(digit).(digit)(digit) miles - " my goal is to remove these 16 characters on each line

Tags: python

Been stuck on this for a week!

Here are the lines of the .txt file I am trying to strip the prefixes of:

```
, 3.33 miles - 20314
, 4.3 miles - 21
, 5.64 miles - 432
, 5.81 miles - 5205
, 6.02 miles - 503
, 6.78 miles - 5125
, 7.2 miles - 423
, 7.5 miles - 2265
, 8.89 miles - 622
```

The goal is to use python to strip the beginning characters starting with the comma and ending with the empty space after the dash from each line.

Comment: If the number after the hyphen is always a 3-digit number, you can just do `s[-3:]`. Otherwise just search at which index the hyphen is and then you can slice based on that.

Comment: What's shown in your question isn't a list. Please [edit] your question put the data in a valid Python list form.

Comment: what is the output you want?

Comment: output wanted would be: 20314 \n 21 \n 432 \n 5205 \n 503 \n 5125 \n 423 \n 2265 \n 622

Comment: `last_nums = '\n'.join(l.split(' - ')[-1] for l in data)`

Answer (score 0):

If the number of characters from the end is always the same you can use the generator to edit the current list.

```
listT = [', 3.33 miles - 203',', 4.3 miles - 215',', 5.64 miles - 432',', 5.81 miles - 520',', 6.02 miles - 503',', 6.78 miles - 512',', 7.2 miles - 423',', 7.5 miles - 226',', 8.89 miles - 622']

listT = [name[-3:] for name in listT ]
```